# Visual Studio 2010 .RC file dialog margins are rest when it is saved

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a legacy .rc file that was created in VS 6.0 C++ and upgraded to new editors over time. Currently we are editing it in VS2010. When i add a new string through the editor, all of the dialog sizing in the  ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED  GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO  information is reset to BEGIN, 50 END and I use beyond compare to reset it. I can believe there might be a sin from the past causing this, but I would like to know if there is something I can hunt to solve this problem.

Comment: Have the service packs been applied to VS10?

Comment: sp1 was installed 8/13/2013. Looking at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads. That should cover it. Windows update is disabled by IT.